# How to pass two parameters in android sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to pass two parameters in android sqlite query statement?

My query looks like this, but I am getting error. If I use one where condition its working fine, but I want to use two condition.

```
db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,Source,
                        Dest}, DestStn + "=" + t ,Source + "=" +tt,null,
                        null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `db.rawQuery(Your_Query);`

i think in your case

```
String query = "Select * from "+DB_TABLE+ "Where" +DestStn + "=" + t +"and"+Source + "=" +tt
db.rawQuery(query);
```

Comment: The parametrized syntax mentioned in the other answers is too weird, doesn't work well with integers, and so I am also up voting this answer.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree with this selected answer.

You should not dismiss parametrized methods simply because it is "too weird". Although this solution *would* work, it does not work in all cases and can be dangerous in some. This solution did not work for me because I was using SQL unsafe strings. I could of course attempt to scrub and sanitize my inputs, but a parametrized solution is the true solution, instead of a quick-fix such as this.

Answer (score 8):

you sould replace to `"KEY_ROWID = ? AND Source = ?",
         new String[] { t, tt }`

Complete query:

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_ROWID, Source,Dest}, "Source = ? AND DestStn = ?",
     new String[] { tt, t },
     null,
     null,
     null);
```

Comment: i tried with this , but still its not getting values from my db

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,Source,Dest},
                        DestStn + "=" + t +" and "+Source + "=" +tt,null,
                        null, null, null, null);
```